# Revenuecat logging in users with google or apple ids

Tags: revenuecat

I want to integrate my app into a subscription based pricing and i am wondering this. Lets say i want to offer my users a subscription based pricing, is it mandatory to login the user first with google and then hook in revenuecat sdk or how does revenue cat identify the current user to be able to commence the subscription?